# Result showing two rows to one row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I wrote a query to count positive and negative results per day.  My problem is that I am getting two rows per postivie to negative day.

- I want one row with a positive and negative column for each day( no multiple days).

[image]

```
SELECT case([MsrSplatPositive]) when '0' then count([MsrSplatPositive]) end as 'Negative'
,case([MsrSplatPositive]) when '1' then count([MsrSplatPositive]) end as 'Positive'
,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), f.NewsDate, 106) as 'Date'
 FROM [News].[dbo].[Score] s
inner join [News].[dbo].[Feed] f
on f.ScoreId = s.Id
where f.NewsDate between dateadd(day,-30,GETDATE()) and GETDATE()
group by [MsrSplatPositive],CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), f.NewsDate, 106)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove MsrSplatPositive from the GROUP BY.

That is forcing the positive and negative results into different days.

And then use a SUM(CASE...) instead of CASE(COUNT...)

You have this in the SELECT:

```
case([MsrSplatPositive]) when '0' then count([MsrSplatPositive]) end as 'Negative'
```

and instead want this:

```
sum(CASE WHEN MsrSplatPositive = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'Negative'
```

EDIT:

All fixed up should be something like:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN MsrSplatPositive = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 'Negative'
      ,SUM(MsrSplatPositive 'Positive'
      ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), f.NewsDate, 106) as 'Date'
  FROM News.dbo.Score s
       INNER JOIN 
       News.dbo.Feed f on f.ScoreId = s.Id
 WHERE f.NewsDate BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY,-30,GETDATE()) and GETDATE()
 GROUP BY f.NewsDate
```

Comment: I cant remove it, its needed for the select

Comment: @user1354345 it's only 'needed' because your aggregate function is inside your case/when and not wrapping it.

Comment: Right. You need adjustments to your select as well. All of it make sit simpler. I am assuming that MsrSplatPositive a BIT NOT NULL? 1 or 0 only?

Comment: correct, i tried the above code but it was showing individual records per day ( multiple records per day)  I had to convert the bit to int to sum

Comment: This cannot return multiple records per NewsDate. If you have multiple NewsDates on a given date (day) then you do need to convert NewsDate to a date without the time in the GROUP BY. Is that what's happening? –  Karl Kieninger

Comment: I added sum and removed MsrSplatPositive in groupby, this fixed ty

Answer (score 0):

Try this...I haven't run the query but think this should achieve the result. I have modified your original query to return 0 instead of null in the positive and negative column. Then used the modified SQL as a temp table and grouped by the date values.

```
Select Sum(Temp.Negative), Sum(Temp.Positive), Temp.Date From
(
SELECT case([MsrSplatPositive]) when '0' then count([MsrSplatPositive]) 
    else 0 end as 'Negative'
,case([MsrSplatPositive]) when '1' then count([MsrSplatPositive] 
    else 0) end as 'Positive'
,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), f.NewsDate, 106) as 'Date'
FROM [News].[dbo].[Score] s
inner join [News].[dbo].[Feed] f
on f.ScoreId = s.Id
where f.NewsDate between dateadd(day,-30,GETDATE()) and GETDATE()
group by [MsrSplatPositive],CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), f.NewsDate, 106)
) Temp
Group By Temp.Date
```

Hope this helps.